# Dificuldade em recuperar dados de um link no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com o framework Laravel juntamente com a api do instagram e cheguei em um impasse: em uma dada rotina, eu recebo um redirecionamento que devolve o login para minha aplicação, mas o problema é que nesse redirecionamento vem um dado importante para ser usado na aplicação mas ele vem nesse formato que não consigo utilizar: "http://localhost:8000/insta#access_token=dado_que_eu_preciso".

Já tentei usar o mecanismo de rota do próprio Laravel pra tentar obter esse dado mas não tive sucesso. Alguém saberia me ajudar?

Comment: Especifique melhor seu problema, poste partes do seu código, onde está batendo essa url?
Isso tudo vem da api? insta#access_token=dado_que_eu_preciso

Comment: A url é da api. Depois de permitir que meu site tenha acesso aos dados do instagram, o próprio faz esse redirecionamento com o access_token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema usando JavaScript, pegando o dado da hash usando "location.hash" e depois removendo o "#access_token=" usando replace pra, por fim, isolar o valor final que eu queria resgatar da url.